# stripe is there a function to use confirmCardPayment in serverside

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, react-stripe

exists are function that is equavilent to confirmCardPayment but in serverside ?

I need this function in serverside:

```
      const confirmPayment = await stripe?.confirmCardPayment(data, {
        payment_method: paymentMethodReq?.paymentMethod.id
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe provides Payment Intent [Confirmation API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm) at the server, which is equivalent to `stripe.confirmCardPayment`.

You may set the payment method ID (pm_xxx) in [`payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm#confirm_payment_intent-payment_method) parameter when confirming the PI. For example,

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
  'pi_xxx',
  {payment_method: 'pm_xxx'}
);
```